# How did the people of Zmigrod wrap tefilin?

Tags: minhag, tefilin

My family is from there, but we've lost our ancestral minhag due to secularization and subsequent return to different sects within orthodox Judaism. I am just curious in reclaiming my ancestral traditions.

TIA!

Comment: Do you mean http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%BBmigr%C3%B3d

Comment: Do you know for a fact that this particular region of Poland had a separate minhag?

Comment: @Danno, the shtetlach, as a general rule, each had some unique minhagim which did not travel to neighboring communities. Even in Germany, in the centres of the Ashkenazi community, Speyer, Worms, Mainz, and Frankfurt often had differing minhagim and variants in nusach, despite cities' relative closeness.

Comment: @Danno Separate from what? I think that's the whole question: What _minhagim_ did this specific location have? It's localized, but in my opinion not _too_ localized.

Comment: Eli, do you know whether your ancestors were Chassidim or not?

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt The question is about customs in Żmigród, not customs of his ancestors.

Comment: @DoubleAA, From what I have heard, most towns in eastern Europe had a mixture of Chassidim and "Litvaks". As such, an answer that will satisfy both his community and his heritage would necessitate such knowledge.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt Right, but this question is about customs in Żmigród, not customs of his ancestors. So the knowledge isn't necessary.